# String from file doesn't match string in python

Tags: python, string, comparison

I am trying to read data in from a file in python and compare it to see if it matches some of the information. I have this

```
with open("data.dat", "r") as f: #read data in from the file
    for line in f:
        if line is "Static": #this adds the data for the static attack
```

When I read the data in from my file, it skips right over it. I am at a loss why.

Here is my data.dat file.

```
Static
0 10
1 50
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `==` to compare two strings:

```
with open("data.dat", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == "Static":
```

`is` is used to test two objects whether they are the same object (compare identity).

`==` is used to compare two variables' value.

[Python Language Reference - Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value. An object's identity never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the object's address in memory. The `is` operator compares the identity of two objects; the `id()` function returns an integer representing its identity.

Answer (score 0):

For this application, you can use the `in` operator, like so:

```
with open("data.dat", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Static" in line:
            # do something
```

This is if you want any line with the substring "Static" to be caught by the condition, regardless of whether or not it is the only string in the line.

If you strictly want to catch lines that only have the substring "Static" in it, with the exception of trailing whitespaces, then you can use the `==` operator, like so:

```
with open("data.dat", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "Static":
            # do something
```